# ArrayFormula Index Match not working in Google Sheets but working in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets

Please see my example link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t23b_DrZ0meST_j6D9Uvvh3kFaXfHGrqwV1MWLkSwkU/edit?usp=sharing

Sheet 3 Column B should provide the result of which sheet the number in Column A is on. 
The SheetList Named Range has been specified for D2:D3.

In Excel this displays correct showing both Sheet1 & Sheet2 being referenced but will not work in Google Sheets.

Please can someone assist in getting this working in Google Sheets?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm reading you question and example correctly then the following example coul be used in cell B2 Sheet3 and replicated down:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet3!A2,Sheet1!A:A,0)),IF(ISERROR(MATCH(Sheet3!A2,Sheet2!A:A,0)),"Not Found","Sheet2"),"Sheet1")
```

Basically, It looks for the value in cell A2 on Sheet1 first, if it can't find it, it then checks for it on Sheet2. If it can't be found on either, it returns "Not Found".